# Faceted search with PHP and Lucene

Tags: php, zend-framework, search, lucene, faceted-search

Is there any way to create a faceted search using Zend Lucene?

I'm limited to shared hosting, and I don't have any option to use Solr.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt this is supported in the current version of ZF1-Lucene, you should probably use the standalone SOLR on your server and write your own wrappers on top of SOLR for your use. Before writing your own please visit below links to get some insights on an existing libraries available for PHP/Zend on top of SOLR.

1. https://stackoverflow.com/q/19751146/765854
2. https://github.com/bluedaniel/Zend-Service-Solr